# Right to Left Languages

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I use Android Studio's Navigation Drawer Activity in My Application but when I change Language of System to Right to Left Language My Application's UI vary

[Left to right(My main UI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t49I.png)

[Right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVW2v.png)

I want to stay the same upon language change

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your views to remain same set `android:supportsRtl="false"` for API level 17+. And make sure you are not using `start` and `end` as gravity values to any view.Because `start` and `end` are used for applications supporting RTL.Instead use `left` and `right`.

If you want your views to change according to language then set `android:supportsRtl="true"` and set gravity values as `start` and `end` instead of `left` and `right`.

Note: start and end only works with device supporting API level 17+.
For more reference see [This blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html).

Answer (score 2):

If your API is 17+ you can use the:`android:supportsRtl="true"`
in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Just set `android:supportsRtl="@string/is_rtl"` for your application node in the manifest and you are good to go.